# Memory storage in Arduino

Tags: memory, arduino

Is it possible (and how to if so) to essentially download a script in Notepad or a terminal to the Arduino and then pull it back up on another computer?

Comment: just updating my progress for anyone else who might be interested. I was able to connect the Arduino and the Terminal for mac in the same serial COM port. So by communicating to the terminal through the Ardiuno you are in fact able to open exe. or other files using Arduino

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really clear on your question. If you want to store a bunch of text *in memory* on the arduino and then retrieve it on another computer, then yes. Just write it out on serial or via a network port or whatever.

If you want to get the original script back *from a compiled program* then no. It's compiled. You might be able to dump the assembler somehow, but you'd have to decompile it to get anything like the original file back. And it still probably wouldn't be close.

You could do a combination of both, though. When you upload the compiled program, *also* store the original text as data on an attached SD card. You'd have to write a program that did that, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: well im thinking, in terms of Windows, if i upload a batch file to the arduino and then open it on another computer just by pressing the home/reset button, sending it back into the computer. I've already done this through terminal in mac but that was because i had uploaded code to the arduino, then connected both both terminal and the arduino to the same serial port and was able to send the uploaded code to the terminal by pressing the reset button on the arduino. I obviously couldn't upload to the arduino in the same serial port after that because it was being shared by terminal.

Comment: but i was able to upload code onto the arduino, and send it back through the same serial port (proof of concept). But what im wondering is if I could upload a batch file to the arduino and then send it back into the computer the same way but have it recognized by the computer as a batch file after it had been compiled in the arduino just cause whenever you upload something is has to compile first

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible because the programmes uploaded are compiled first. I'm not sure of the details but it would be like trying to get a C programme from an executable.

Comment: What?  The Arduino has EEPROM although its size is extremely limited.  Still, you can store something on it and retrieve it later as long as you had the proper code to do so.  Also, you can use all kinds of external storage shields like SD cards.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought the op meant getting the source from the compiled programme